# Bash for loop with wildcards and hidden files

Tags: bash, loops, scripting, wildcard

Just witting a simple shell script and little confused:

Here is my script:

```
% for f in $FILES; do echo "Processing $f file.."; done
```

The Command:

```
ls -la | grep bash
```

produces:

```
% ls -a | grep bash
.bash_from_cshrc
.bash_history
.bash_profile
.bashrc
```

When

```
FILES=".bash*"
```

I get the same results (different formatting) as ls -a.  However when

```
FILES="*bash*"
```

I get this output:

```
Processing *bash* file..
```

This is not the expected output and not what I expect.  Am I not allowed to have a wild card at the beginning of the file name?  Is the . at the beginning of the file name "special" somehow?

Setting

```
FILES="bash*"
```

Also does not work.

Comment: As Nos said below, you probably want to use a bash flag to modify the behavior.  (shopt -s dotglob)

Comment: This question is the top hit when I search for "bash wildcard hidden files". I suggest changing the accept to the top-voted answer which is the general solution people should use when struggling with this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`FILES=".bash*"` works because the hidden files name begin with a `.`

`FILES="bash*"` doesn't work because the hidden files name begin with a `.` not a `b`

`FILES="*bash*"` doesn't work because the `*` wildcard at the beginning of a string omits hidden files.

Comment: So if I want to do it I should do FILES=".*bash*"?  But what if I want hidden AND not hidden files?

Comment: This is slightly confused because the quotes prevent the wildcards from expanding at all. The expansion happens when you _use_ `$FILES`, unquoted.

Answer (score 66):

The default globbing in bash does not include filenames starting with a . (aka hidden files).

You can change that with

> shopt -s dotglob

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  .a  .b  .c  d  e  f
$ ls *
d  e  f
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls *
.a  .b  .c  d  e  f
$
```

To disable it again, run `shopt -u dotglob`.

Answer (score 18):

If you want hidden and non hidden, set dotglob (bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob
for file in *
do
 echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the `.` at the front is special, and normally won't be matched by a `*` wildcard, as documented in the bash man page (and common to most Unix shells):

> When a pattern is used for pathname expansion, the character “.”
>       at the start of a name or immediately following a slash must
>       be matched explicitly, unless the shell  option  *dotglob*  is
>       set.   When  matching  a  pathname, the slash character must
>      always be matched explicitly.  In  other  cases,  the  “.”
>      character  is not treated specially.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to include hidden files, you can specify two wildcards; one for the hidden files, and another for the others.

```sh
for f in .[!.]* *; do
    echo "Processing $f file.."
done
```

The wildcard `.*` would expand to all the dot files, but that includes the parent directory, which you normally would want to exclude; so `.[!.]*` matches all files whose first character is a dot, but the second one isn't.

If you have other files with two leading dots, you need to specify a third wildcard to cover those but exclude the parent directory! Try `..?*` which requires there to be at least one character after the second dot.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in directory/{.[!.]*,*};do echo $file;done
```

Should echo either hidden files and normal file. Thanks to tripleee for the `.[!.]*` tip.
The curly brackets permits a 'or' in the pattern matching. {pattern1,pattern2}