# Bash loop through directory including hidden file

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a way to make a simple loop in bash over everything my directory contains, i.e. files, directories and links including hidden ones.

I will prefer if it could be specifically in bash but it has to be the most general. Of course, file names (and directory names) can have white space, break line, symbols. Everything but "/" and ASCII NULL (0×0), even at the first character. Also, the result should exclude the '.' and '..' directories.

Here is a generator of files on which the loop has to deal with :

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p test
cd test
touch A 1 ! "hello world" \$\"sym.dat .hidden " start with space" $'\n start with a newline' 
mkdir -p ". hidden with space" $'My Personal\nDirectory'
```

So my loop should look like (but has to deal with the tricky stuff above):

```
for i in * ;
  echo ">$i<"
done
```

My closest try was the use of `ls` and bash array, but it is not working with, is:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
l=( $(ls -A .) )
for i in ${l[@]} ; do
echo ">$i<"
done
unset IFS
```

Or using bash arrays but the ".." directory is not exclude:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
l=( [[:print:]]* .[[:print:]]* )
for i in ${l[@]} ; do
echo ">$i<"
done
unset IFS
```

Comment: What is the use case? When would you need to include `.` and `..` in the list?

Comment: `While read line; do; echo $line; done <<<$(ls -a) ` should work i think

Comment: Duplicate ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135770/bash-for-loop-with-wildcards-and-hidden-files ?

Comment: If you have to modify IFS (you don't here if you follow Ashish' comment), then I advice you to open a subshell (parenthesis) to avoid any side-effect: ( IFS='stuff' ; do; do )

Comment: @l0b0 On the contrary, I need to avoid them (because of recursive call)

Comment: @Ashish This doesn't work, alas !

Comment: @BlueMoon This is not enougth, `shopt -s dotglob` but doesn't deal with newline character in filenames

Comment: Sorry i added extra ; there after do `while read line ; do echo $line ; done <<< $(ls -a | grep -v -w ".") ` this worked in my case when i tried on rhel machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chepner noted in the comments below, this solution assumes you're running GNU `bash` along with GNU `find` GNU `sort`...

GNU `find` can be prevented from recursing into subdirectories with the `-maxdepth` option.  Then use `-print0` to end every filename with a `0x00` byte instead of the newline you'd usually get from `-print`.

The `sort -z` sorts the filenames between the `0x00` bytes.

Then, you can use `sed` to get rid of the dot and dot-dot directory entries (although GNU `find` seems to exclude the `..` already).

I also used `sed` to get read of the `./` in front of every filename.  `basename` could do that too, but older systems didn't have `basename`, and you might not trust it to handle the funky characters right.

(These `sed` commands each required two cases: one for a pattern at the start of the string, and one for the pattern between `0x00` bytes.  These were so ugly I split them out into separate functions.)

The `read` command doesn't have a `-z` or `-0` option like some commands, but you can fake it with `-d ""` and blanking the `IFS` environment variable.

The additional `-r` option prevents a backslash-newline combo from being interpreted as a line continuation.  (A file called `backslash\\nnewline` would otherwise be mangled to `backslashnewline`.)  It might be worth seeing if other backslash-combos get interpreted as escape sequences.

```sh
remove_dot_and_dotdot_dirs()
{
    sed \
      -e 's/^[.]\{1,2\}\x00//' \
      -e 's/\x00[.]\{1,2\}\x00/\x00/g'
}

remove_leading_dotslash()
{
    sed \
      -e 's/^[.]\///' \
      -e 's/\x00[.]\//\x00/g'
}

IFS=""
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
  sort -z |
  remove_dot_and_dotdot_dirs |
  remove_leading_dotslash |
  while read -r -d "" filename
  do
      echo "Doing something with file '${filename}'..."
  done
```

Comment: This is the best answer at the moment. I was looking for something more "bash" based (using arrays for example) but it seems to be less portable than this one. Thanks

Comment: This isn't portable: it requires GNU `find` for `-print0` and GNU `sort` for `-z`. Also, `read -d` is a `bash` extension as well.

Comment: @chepner: I see that as OK, because the question itself was also non-portable.  Escaping or otherwise handling shell metacharacters depends heavily on what shell you're running.  (Also, this question was tagged [bash].)  I did allude to GNU `find`, but not clearly...  I'll make that more explicit.

Answer (score 28):

`*` doesn't match files beginning with `.`, so you just need to be explicit:

```
for i in * .[^.]*; do
    echo ">$i<"
done
```

`.[^.]*` will match all files and directories starting with `.`, followed by a non-`.` character, followed by zero or more characters. In other words, it's like the simpler `.*`, but excludes `.` and `..`. If you need to match something like `..foo`, then you might add `..?*` to the list of patterns.

Comment: A loop is the wrong way to go through a directory structure though - you have to use recursion.

Comment: `bash` 4 can use recursive patterns like `**/*` to iterate through the directory hierarchy. (`shopt -s globstar` enables `**`, which represents 0 or more directories in a matching path).

Comment: The file substitution doesn't work if the number of files is too big

Comment: `bash` iterates over the pattern internally; too many files is only an issue for building argument lists to pass to external commands (e.g., `ls *` can fail if `*` produces too many files to fit in the space allocated for the argument list to pass to `ls`).

Comment: I agree with your approach @chepner, your method is much better approach then my answer + 1Up for your answer

Comment: @chepner - amazing - I hadn't come across that pattern in bash's documentation - thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try the find command, something like:

```
find .
```

That will list all the files in all recursive directories.

To output only files excluding the leading . or .. try:

```
find . -type f -printf %P\\n
```

Comment: This include the `.` and `..` path but also doesn't deal with space nor newline character in filenames

Comment: I would amend that to `find . -type f`, since the OP is interested in files, not directories and other entities....

Comment: @twalberg Intersting but it gives additional "./" before every filename output

Comment: @Ashish That can easily be fixed by using `sed`... e.g. `find . -type f | sed -e 's;^./;;'`.

Comment: I know that find + sed can be the solution, but I found it not proper enough (in particular to deal with space and newline in filenames). I guess bash can provide me something easy to loop over a directory.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most favorable way but I tried bellow thing

```
while read line ; do echo $line; done <<< $(ls -a | grep -v -w ".")
```

check the below trail which I did
[image: Check the output]